# Angular2 - SVG with ng-style

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, svg

I am drawing an SVG Lines with ng-repeat and want to change the translate of each line. However Using ng-attr-style I can't get the style to be applied.

my-component.js:

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: 'my-component.html'
})

export class MyComponent{
  lines: [
    { translateX: 0.0, translateY: 0.0, weight: 0.40, x1: 86.69, y1: 1, x2: 98.91, y2: 1 },
{ translateX: 0.0, translateY: 0.0, weight: 0.40, x1: 85.31, y1: 9.67, x2: 98.23, y2: 9.67 }
  ]
}
```

my-component-html:

```html
<svg id="lines" viewBox="0 0 320.6 542.59">
  <line *ngFor="let line of lines" ng-attr-style="{'transform': 'translate('+line.translateX+'px, ' + line.translateY+'px)'}" class="line" [attr.x1]="line.x1" [attr.y1]="line.y1" [attr.x2]="line.x2" [attr.y2]="line.y2"/>
</svg>
```

This is what I see when inspecting the element in the dom:

```
<line _ngcontent-ssx-9="" class="line" ng-attr-style="{'transform': 'translate('+line.translateX+'px, ' + line.translateY+'px)'}" x1="189.1" y1="226.41" x2="212.06" y2="226.41"></line>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-attr-*` is being used by Angular 1, you should be using `[attr.style]`(property binding)

```
[attr.style]="{'transform': 'translate('+line.translateX+'px, ' + line.translateY+'px)'}"
```

Comment: Seems to be working, thanks. However I am getting following message in the console: WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value